# Having issues initialising my selenium tests using the [TestInitialize]

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been attempting to learn selenium in c# and in the past day or so it's developed into using the testinitialize. Before I ran everything from my test method and it worked great the long term goal is for me to be able to load a page on the initialize then login in one test add posts on another test etc. I don't want to be loading up and logging in every time I'd like it to be free flowing from the point of logging in. At the moment I'm getting something in the wrong place as now it's just firing up a blank firefox page and doing nothing. I've kept it simple at the moment so I can get to grips with it. So the code below should load up wikipedia and check for some text in the heading.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
namespace SeleniumPractice
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Setup
    {

        IWebDriver driver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void GoToWiki()
        {
            //Create an instance of the firefox driver.
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void VerifyHelloWorld()
        {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program");
                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                string actualvalue = driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstHeading")).Text;
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                Assert.AreEqual(actualvalue, "\"Hello, World!\" program");

        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Teardown()
        {
                driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Also I'm getting a green line under IwebDriver driver; in my class. With this error.

```
field 'seleniumPractice.Setup.driver' is never assigned to, and always have its default value null
```

I put this here because i noticed the test method didn't recognise the driver anymore when I moved it out of the test method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the compiler warning and the blank Firefox window is that you are not actually assigning the driver field with a reference to a new FirefoxDriver object in GoToWiki(), you are actually declaring a new variable that is scoped only to that method and assigning a reference to a new FirefoxDriver object to that variable. The field is null when you call GoToUrl on it in VerifyHelloWorld(). Try this edit:

```
 [TestInitialize]
    public void GoToWiki()
    {
        //Create an instance of the firefox driver.
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    }
```